# Posting parameters to url from another page

Tags: php

Please I need help figuring out how to handle a redirect from a link as this:
http://link.site.com/636337 to http://new.site.com/index.php?param=202020

Note the domain is selected from database based on the ID (http://link.site.com/636337 636337 is the ID here) and it points to domain http://new.site.com/index.php

All am trying to do is add the parameters to the domain to become http://new.site.com/index.php?param=202020

Thanks as your help would be higly regarded and appreciated.

here is my code:

````
include "inc/config.php";

if(!isset($_GET["id"])) {
    addLog(1);
    http_response_code(404);
    exit("<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p></body></html>");
}

$getid = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM links WHERE uniq_id = :id");
$getid->bindParam("id", $_GET["id"]);
$getid->execute();
if($getid->rowCount() == 0) {
    addLog(1);
    http_response_code(404);
    exit("<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p></body></html>");
}
$id = $getid->fetch()["id"];

// Only select 10 domains for performance
$getdomains = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM domains WHERE link_id = :id AND status = 0 LIMIT 10");
$getdomains->bindParam("id", $id);
$getdomains->execute();
$domains = array();

if($getdomains->rowCount() == 0) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit("<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p></body></html>");
}

foreach ($getdomains->fetchAll() as $domain) {
    $domains[] = $domain["link"];
}


//Redirect to first url to the link with parameter value $paramid
if(empty($domains)) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit("<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p></body></html>");
}
$paramid = "20202020";
$urls = $domains[0];
//echo($urls);

header("Location: ".$url."?email=".$paramid); ```

The Problem is, it redirects only to the domain http://new.site.com/index.php but without the parameters
````

Comment: How does it work/not work now? Can you give an example of an error you are receiving, or how it currently behaves?

Comment: You are asking about how to construct the link, or make the rewriting work?

Comment: it redirects only to the domain http://new.site.com/index.php but without the parameters

Comment: The only redirect I see, is `header("Location: ".$url."?email=".$paramid);` How you expect `?email=` to magically turn into `?param=` however is a secret currently at most only you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a typo. Check the end of your PHP code:

```php
$paramid = "20202020";
$urls = $domains[0];
//echo($urls);

header("Location: ".$url."?email=".$paramid);
```

You create the variable `$urls`, but you use `$url` for the Location header. `$url` is not defined anywhere, so I assume it is an empty variable here.
Write `$url = $domains[0];` instead.

#### More debugging

Keep in mind that a `Location` header works immediately. So `echo` here should be followed by exit for your debugging purposes.

I would suggest you make the location value a variable so you can echo it easily as well:

```php
$url = $domains[0];
$location = $url . '?email=' . $paramid;
// echo $location; exit;

header("Location: " . $location);
```

Help yourself debug easier is always worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. and gave a clearer understanding.

Comment: Okay great  Mark this as the solution to mark this question as closed.